# Shortest line for multiple points using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a dataset with a few points, and I'd like to know the shortest LINE to interconnect every point. No need for routing etc. The result should be a sorted list with points or a linestring.

I have an idea about the concept but I don't know where to start. This nut is hard to crack. It's like a Dijkstra-one-to-many problem, but without the routing, so should be easier and faster.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that what you want to accomplish is a [Hamiltonian path](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Hamiltonian_path).

> In the mathematical field of graph theory, a Hamiltonian path (or
>   traceable path), is a path in an undirected graph which visits each
>   vertex exactly once.

[image]

PostGIS 2.0 has topology support so maybe you can implement it with that. Not sure if there are out of the box solutions though. Be warned that this is an NP-complete problem. Finding the path is a challenge in itself, let alone the shortest. Though if your points aren't that  many then should be able to manage. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution and it works! For everyone else, who has a similar problem - read these articles on Wikipedia and start your research there:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_%28optimization%29

The nearest neighbour is already a strong solution, with k-opt you can optimize, but to optimize 5% further down you need a lot of time. I tested with my 'raw' data and had 10ms to get a nearest neighbour solution on 100 way points but further down the k-opt is running for several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

R.K.'s answer seems not useful since the OP doesn't have a graph but only a set of points without "routes", so a graph can always be done.

The TSP and the Local search (optimization) are more suited, only issue is how to implement these algorithms on a GIS.