# how to find Shortest line for a bunch of points(Hamiltonian path) using pgrouting v3.3

Tags: pgrouting, travelling-salesman

it looks like tsp problem. but just as [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35505/shortest-line-for-a-bunch-of-points-in-postgis) describes, I don't want to go back after visiting the last node, so using pgr_tsp returns the wrong answer for me. does pgrouting have any function to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an artificial node, which is connected to all other nodes, you want to visit. Now set the cost to 0 (or very small) for all these artificial connections. Now run TSP on the set of nodes, which includes your desired node + the artificial node.